# Macro parameter restrictions in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, macros

I'm porting to windows with visual studio 2015 some code that builds in linux with gcc.

In VS I get the error error C2059: syntax error: '+=' when using the macro DEFOP with the parameter "+=", the same with the other parameters. This is the code:

```
#define DEFOP(OP) \
    Matrix& Matrix::operator OP (const double& val) { \
        for (int i = 0; i < _n; i++) { \
            _data[i] OP val; \
        } \
    return *this; \
    } \
    Matrix& Matrix::operator OP (const Matrix& that) { \
    if (_rows != _rows || _cols != that._cols) { \
            throw Exception (String ( \
                "Matrix size mismatch in operation '%s': " \
        "(%d,%d) vs. (%d,%d).", \
                __STRING(OP), _rows, _cols, that._rows, that._cols)); \
    } \
        for (int i = 0; i < _n; i++) { \
            _data[i] OP that._data[i]; \
        } \
    return *this; \
    }
DEFOP(+=);
DEFOP(-=);
DEFOP(*=);
DEFOP(/=);
#undef DEFOP
```

Does anybody know how to modify this code so that it builds in VS?

Comment: What if you replace `__STRING(OP)` with `#OP`?

Comment: I would not use a macros in this way. Difficult to debug for a start. Why not just write the code out long hand. Easy to do and all editors have a search and replace functionality.

Comment: PS: `_rows != _rows` is an error for a start

Comment: The #OP work! I wonder if this same syntax will work in gcc. The code is meant to build in gcc too. @SingerOfTheFall if you put this as answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @EdHeal I'm just getting to build some third party library in windows, so nothing I can do about design. and yes _rows != _rows looks like an error??

Comment: So this "third" party is giving you code that does not compile? Seems rather strange. Why not get them to fix it?

Comment: I changed it to _rows !=  that._rows which seems the right form. Thanks for pointing out that. I'll upvote your comment

Comment: Vote to close. This is anything but minimal, and we already require minimal examples for proper readable code. Please reduce the problem to a one-line macro definition. You may very well discover a solution in the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `__STRING` is a non-standard macro, not all compilers accept it. The common way to use a macro parameter as a string literal is to use `#`, i.e. you should replace `__STRING(OP)` with `#OP`